Does window.document.querySelector have access to the shadowDOM?
I have code like this, which selects a specific meta tag from the document. What I'm expecting from this code is to select and fetch the first tag out of the many tags in the head.
This code has been working fine until now, but something happened to select the meta tag inside the iframe's shadowDOM instead. As far as I know, the iframe works independently and is not accessible, so why would I want to access it?
The querySelector is looking for the first element, so even if I had access to the iframe, wouldn't the element in the head be the first?
const getDisplayLocation = () => {
  return window.document.querySelector('meta[name="temp_role"]').content;
};

Actually I modified the code to get access to the document.head, but I don't know why I was able to access the iframe, shouldn't it only be accessible through the contentWindow?

Yes you're right it's supposed to not be able to access another document, which your iframe's content is. Please share a minimal example showing how this all happens.

You ca use window.top to get the main window
window.top.document.querySelector('meta[name="temp_role"]');


I was under the understanding that the iframe exists in the child of the document. May I ask why window.top is used to select the top document?

@madid I had to do something very similar, if the code is running from an iframe window.top allows it to start from the main DOM (top).  But this should only work if the frame is from the same domain
